# Only add last element of an array to existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I have an existing array that as I scroll, I am trying to add more elements to.

I am using [rss2json](https://rss2json.com) to convert an rss feed to json.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getRssFeed();  // returns 4 items
}
```

Here is how I am adding more items:

```
this.count++;
this.podcastService.getRssFeed(this.rssUrl, this.count)
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            for (const episodes of data.items) {
                this.episodes.push(episodes);  // returns 5 items
                // const episode = this.episodes[episodes.length - 1]
            }
            event.target.complete();
            console.log(data);
            ...
```

Count is correctly getting incremented. But each time `getRssFeed` is called the entire array is returned. Each time with the correct length.
I am not sure how to `pop` all of the array elements that come back except for the last one.

I've also tried something like this to try and `push()` only the last array element returned. Still no luck.

```
const episode = this.episodes[episodes.length - 1]
```

For example, if on initial load I get:

```
[foo, bar]
```

when I scroll, I am getting back:

```
[foo, bar, baz]
```

I only want to add `baz` to the already existing array.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you try `this.episodes.push(episodes[episodes.length-1])`? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, I apologize I updated my question.

Comment: Just to understand, `data.items` is an array of episodes? In that case you can try `if (data) this.episodes.push(data.items.pop());`

Comment: @Shidersz you are correct - and it worked! I was trying to figure out ways of using `splice` and other things. Please update your suggestion as the answer and I'll mark it.

If you don't mind, can you provide some explanation? Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: @Shidersz—that also modifies *data.items*. I don't see the point of *for..of* when all the OP wants is to pop the last item…?

Comment: @RobG I know it changes `data.items`, but for what he explain, he don't wanted the others items...

Comment: @RobG correct - I only wanted the last item in the array that was returned from my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution you can try is to change the next portion of code:

```
if (data)
{
    for (const episodes of data.items)
    {
        this.episodes.push(episodes);  // returns 5 items
        // const episode = this.episodes[episodes.length - 1]
    }
...
}
```

By this one:

```
if (data)
{
    let lastEpisode = data.items.pop();
    this.episodes.push(lastEpisode);
...
}
```

Here, `pop()` is used to remove the last element from `data.items` array and returns that element, we save it on the variable `lastEpisode` and finally we push it on your `episodes` array. Another solution, that won't change `data.items` array could be:

```
if (data)
{
    let lastEpisode = data.items[data.items.length - 1];
    this.episodes.push(lastEpisode);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to add just the latest items returned from the `getRssFeed` service to the `episodes` list. You can make use of the Array spread syntax to update the episodes list on every call of the `getRssFeed` service.

You can update the function to make it look like this:

```
this.count++; 
this.podcastService.getRssFeed(this.rssUrl, this.count)
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            this.episodes = [
               // This keeps the previous episodes
               ...this.episodes,
               // This adds the last item returned to the array
               data.items[data.items.length -1],
            ]
        }
        event.target.complete();
        console.log(data);
        ...
```

Comment: Creating a new array every time seems inefficient, why not just `this.episodes.push(data.items[data.items.length -1])`?

Comment: I wish I could accept all of these. Thank you so much everyone!!